# What's the meaning of "cell range as a formula" in MS Excel / Apple Numbers

Tags: excel, numbers, range, formula, cell

Step to reproduce:

1. Create an Excel file or Numbers file.
2. Fill cells from A1 to A10 with 1~10 (An has value n).
3. Assign cells from B1 to B11 with formula $A$1:$A$10 (WITHOUT SUM function).

   And we will get this.
   [image]
   [image]
4. The same formula $A$1:$A$10 gets different values from B1 to B11.
   Bn has same value as An when 1 <= n <=10, and B11 got error value.
5. The same thing happens with formula of single row or column.
   But if formula cell range has more than one rows/columns. All cell with formula gets error value.
6. The same logic happens in both Excels & Numbers, And other similar softwares.

So I want to make sure that, is this a feature or just a bug? Is there some documentation related to this?

Comment: This isn't a feature nor a bug. It's an incorrect formula.

Comment: `$A$1:$A$10` this shouldn't give any error. What is your actual goal?

Comment: To  Enigmativity:  But most similar softwares gets the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a feature called "Implicit Intersection". Effectively the formula says: Get the value in A1:A10 that is in the same row as this formulae. That works if the formula is in 1 to 10, but fails for row 11 because there is no row 11 in the range A1:A10.

Note that your formula doesn't work as described in Excel 365. Instead, you'd need to use the new implicit intersection operator, like @$A$1:$A$10 see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34

Comment: `@$A$1:$A$10` this will show only first result.

Comment: @Harun24HR correct, it shows the first result (A1) when in B1, then A2 when in B2, etc. That is the definition of implicit intersection.